# does fgetc() and getc() move the stream indicator in every situation it's called?

Tags: c, input

I need to write a loop that will use fgetc() to consume all unwanted characters in a stream after reading the desired input like so:

```
while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n' && fgetc(stdin) != EOF) {
fgetc(stdin);
}
```

My question is whether the fget() in the logic statement will actually consume a stream character or not. Does this loop consume 3 characters per loop or 1?

Comment: Easy way to find out is to `printf("%c\n", fgetc(stdin));` in the body of the loop. Then run the program, type "hello, world" and press enter.

Comment: Logic operations are guaranteed to short-circuit. That is, if given the or statement `A || B`, if `A` is true, `B` will not be evaluated. If `A` is false, `A` and `B` will both be evaluated.

Comment: This is an infinite loop if I ever saw one.

Comment: @n.m. Not quite infinite: Consider input `"\n"`.

Comment: Why do you think it would *not* consume a character each time `fgetc` is called? That is, how could the `fgetc` function possibly decide that it should not consume a character?

Comment: @chux yes sometimes you get lucky.